# Jenkins project generated by Job DSL is not triggered.

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a project, named `Demo`, which doesn't do anything in particular.

I have a DSL script, like the following:

```
def gitUrl = 'GIT_URL'

job('unit-tests') {
    scm {
        git(gitUrl)
    }
    triggers {
        buildResult('H/* * * * *') {
            combinedJobs()
            triggerInfo('Demo', BuildResult.SUCCESS, BuildResult.UNSTABLE)
        }
    }
}
```

Now what I'm wanting to do, is that when the `Demo` project runs successfully (it checks out a PHP application from Github), I want the `unit-tests` job to run.

Currently, when the `Demo` project is built, the `unit-tests` job never gets run.

I'm guessing my DSL script is incorrect, but I'm not sure why

Comment: Does `unit-tests` job generated from DSL script has entry `[BuildResultTrigger] - Monitor build results of other jobs` in **Build Triggers** section? Also check plug-ins [versions](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.triggers.TriggerContext.buildResult).

Comment: @luka5z Yes I can see that section, but non of the check boxes are checked for it

Comment: have you tried with an example from API viewer?

Comment: You mean: https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/ ?

Comment: I mean https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.triggers.TriggerContext.buildResult.

Comment: Yes, you can see in my example, which i have taken from the example you provided. In the `trigger` is this what this job `will` trigger next, or what job this is triggered by? Like I said, `Demo` runs first. This needs to trigger the `unit-tests` job, which, currently doesn't happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem. The check box is not set when running the seed job for the first time. But it's set after running the seed job a second time. Must be a problem in the BuildResultTrigger plugin. Please file a bug report in the Jenkins JIRA: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/projects/JENKINS

But you do not necessarily need to use the BuildResultTrigger plugin. You can use the built-in "Build after other projects are built" option, see https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/job-triggers-upstream.

```
job('unit-tests') {
    triggers {
        upstream('Demo', 'UNSTABLE')
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought there must have been some kind of bug. I ran it more than once though and the checkbox was still not checked. I forgot about the `upstream` trigger, so I'll give that a try

Answer (score 0):

Use upstream which adds the "Build after other projects are built" trigger. see https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/job-triggers-upstream

```
def gitUrl = 'GIT_URL'

job('unit-tests') {
    scm {
        git(gitUrl)
    }
    triggers {
        buildResult('H/* * * * *') {
            upstream('Demo', 'UNSTABLE')
        }
    }
}
```